# Как правильно сделать вывод значения переменных php в html таблицу

Tags: php, phpquery

Есть код:

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

require 'phpQuery-onefile.php';


echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>";
function parser ($url,$start,$end) {

 if ($start < $end) {
 
  $file = file_get_contents($url);
  $file = preg_replace('#<!--.*#','',$file);
  $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);  

   foreach ($doc->find('.product-list') as $position) {
    $position = pq($position);

                $articul = nl2br($position->find('.name > span:even(1)')->text());
                $articul = str_replace("Артикул:", " ", $articul);
                
                $price = nl2br($position->find('.actions div.price')->html());
                $price = preg_replace("/[^0-9,\n.грн]/u", '',$price);

               
                
   } 
    $file = 'database.html';
    $inFile = "<tr><td>".$articul."</td><td>".$price."</td></tr>";
    
    file_put_contents($file, $inFile, FILE_APPEND);

    echo '<pre>';
    echo '<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpading=0"><th>Артикул</th><th>Цена товара</th>'; 
    echo "<tr><td>".$articul."</td><td>".$price."</td></tr>";
    echo '</pre>';      

   $next = $doc->find('.pagination .active')->next()->find('a')->attr('href'); 
  
  if ( !empty($next) ) {
   $start++; 
   parser($next, $start, $end);
  }
 } 
}

$url = 'https://www.agro-center.com.ua/combines-a/spare-parts-for-grain-harvesters/john-deere-c/?limit=1514';
$start = 0;
$end = 1;
parser($url,$start,$end);

phpQuery::unloadDocuments();

?>
```

Данные из переменных $articul и $price выводятся таблицей следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как правильно оформить строку кода:

```html
$file = 'database.html';
$inFile = "<tr><td>".$articul."</td><td>".$price."</td></tr>";    
file_put_contents($file, $inFile, FILE_APPEND);
```

Чтобы у файле database.html была точно такая же таблица как и при выводе?
Буду очень благодарен за ответ! Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

Замените свою часть кода

```
$file = 'database.html';
$inFile = "<tr><td>".$articul."</td><td>".$price."</td></tr>";

file_put_contents($file, $inFile, FILE_APPEND);
```

на эту

```
$file = 'database.html';
$inFile = '';
$inFile .= '<pre>';
$inFile .= '<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpading=0"><th>Артикул</th><th>Цена товара</th>';    
$inFile .= "<tr><td>".$articul."</td><td>".$price."</td></tr>";
$inFile .= '</pre>'; 

file_put_contents($file, $inFile, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: это прекрасно :) 
Подскажите, а как у файле database.html сделать заготовочку, чтобы данные, которые я туда ложу корректно отображались? 
Имеется ввиду начало html файла. Потому что оно стирается :
<html>
<head>
  <title>Parser</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>